# Use a ROW_NUMBER() in queries instead of OFFSET/FETCH

Tags: c#, lambda, asp.net-core, pagination

How would I implement `ROW_NUMBER()` / `UseRowNumberForPaging()`  for my statement in asp.net core?

I am working with SQL Server 2008, .Net Core and a newer version of RC.

```
public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, 
    int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    var count = await source.CountAsync();
    var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
    return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this query uses OFFSET/FETCH and why would you want to use ROWNUMBER() here?

Comment: It does because I am working in .net core and using SQL 2008.

Comment: It works in 2012 SQL and up and it says to use this to make it backwards compatible. I just don't know how to use it.

Comment: So you specifically don't want to use OFFSET, it's not that you need ROWNUMBER?

Comment: Well type is the IQueryable what is the source?